# How to use modifier in product_action_attribute Form?

Tags: magento2, catalog, eav, massaction, eav-attributes

I have created an **eav attribute** and modified the field inside edit product form, that was easy. But in products mass action (Update attributes) page, the field I have created, by **eav Attribute** and modified, doesn't apply, It gets the default eav attribute field type etc. How could I apply the modifier for that form?

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {

    $fieldCode = 'material';

    $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
    $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');

    if (!$elementPath) {
        return $meta;
    }

    $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
        $containerPath,
        $meta,
        [
            'children' => [
                $fieldCode => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'select',
                                'componentType' => 'field',
                                'component' => 'VENDOR/js/components/select',
                                'filterOptions' => false,
                                'chipsEnabled' => true,
                                'disableLabel' => true,
                                'levelsVisibility' => '0',
                                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                                'filterOptions' => true,
                                'dataType'  => 'string',
                                'multiple'  => true,
                                'showTree'  => true,
                                'options' => $this->getOptions(),
                                'config' => [
                                    'dataScope' => $fieldCode,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    return $meta;
}
```

That's how I did in edit Product form, but It doesn't apply to mass actions update attributes form.